# What is the missing of "version.lib" in process of building clang with clang-cl?

Tags: visual-c++, clang, llvm

I successfully built standalone llvm on windows with `clang-cl` (clang 8.0 downloadable binary) against back-end msvc build tool 2017 with windows 10 sdk using `cmake`/`ninja`

After that when I was building standalone clang, it reported "version.lib" in linking phase of `clang-rename.exe` is missing.

> LINK Pass 1: command "....
>
> " failed (exit code 1104) with the following output:
>
> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'version.lib'

The weird thing is that word `version.lib` was slabbed in place amoung various `lib\clang?????.lib`s and the leading `-LIBPATH:llvm\\.\lib`

I tried looking for `version.lib` in both build folders of llvm and clang, and found none.

Am I supposed to have `verson.lib` in `llvm\lib`?

What am I missing here?

Comment: It is a standard SDK library.  Either use the full path or tweak  LIBPATH to also name the SDK directory, like C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10586.0\um\x86

Comment: That's correct! I forgot about it. Thank you.